# Git Command To recover lost commit

Tags: git

I have created several changes in my project(around 24) and i got error while pushing them. I again made some more changes but now while committing i'm only getting recently changed files.. I want my previously changed files too..

Is there any command or procedure to retrieve back my previous changes ?

Comment: If i'm getting this right, you had total of 2 commits. You pushed first one and failed, but you kept working till 2nd commit? Also where are you pushing to?

Answer (score 0):

See 
`git reflog`

then
`git checkout <commit_hash>` for commits from the list.